# How do I prevent an IndexOutOfBoundsException error in this Java code?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

Basically I just want an error message when there are no more records to show in the array list. What do I need to tweak?

```
         public void nextRecord()
          { 

           if(records.size() > 0)
           {
              recordCount++;
              if(records.get(recordCount) != null)
              {
                 String[] array = records.get(recordCount).split(",");
                 String item = array[0].trim().replaceAll("\"", "");
                 String number = array[1].trim();
                 String cost = array[2].trim();
                 String amnt = array[3].trim();

                 txtItem.setText(item);
                 txtNumber.setText(number);
                 txtCost.setText(cost);
                 txtAmount.setText(amnt);
              } 

           }
           else if (records.get(recordCount) == null)
           {
              JOptionPane.showMessa
```

Comment: You don't  tell us which line is throwing the exception, or what "records" is.  Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: (1) You probably need a `while` loop instead of the `if`.  (2) `recordCount++;` needs to be pushed to the end of the `while` loop.

Comment: You get the error while reading the _last_ record, don't you?

Comment: @devnull yes, you are correct

Answer (score 2):

Check the size of arrayList before calling get() like,

```
if(recordCount< records.size() && records.get(recordCount) != null)
 {
    //Do the processing
 } else {
    JOptionPane.showMessa
 }
```